# Discord py bot not triggering and ignoring commands

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I have this bot that checks everytime someone sends a message using an `on_message` event and for some reason the other commands that the bot has seem to be ignored.
I figured that out after removing the function of checking the msgs and the commands work pretty fine.

Here is the `on_message` event code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    text = message.content
    chann = message.channel.id
    yes1 = False
    yes = False
    for ide in ids:
        if message.author.id == ide:
            yes1 = True
    for strf in comms:
        if text.startswith(strf):
            yes = True
    if (yes == False) and (yes1 == False) and (chann == 822089739502616576) and (message.author.id != 769302967803183124):
        print(message.author.id)
        msg = await message.channel.send('lahne kel el commands ye bhim')
        await message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('deleting message')
        await msg.delete()
    if yes and (message.author.id != 769302967803183124) and (message.channel.id == 331562608467509249):
        print(message.author.id)
        msg = await message.channel.send('mech lahne tekteb el commands ye bhim')
        await message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('deletingmessage')
        await msg.delete()
    if yes1 and (chann == 331562608467509249) and (message.author.id != 769302967803183124):
        await message.delete()
```

I don't know where the problem comes from.

Comment: suggestion: consider using 'else' for your if statements above instead of repeating with another 'if', should a message event pass and go into one of your ifs, there is no need to check the rest of them, since that same message will not pass any other if checks from what i can see. having some 'perhaps silly' common practices like this can save you later from poor performance and bugs. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` to the end of your on_message coroutine.

As the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) state:

> By default, this coroutine is called inside the on_message() event. If you choose to override the on_message() event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well.

Comment: thanks a lot. it seems i didnt read the documentation that well haha.anyway it worked thanks  dude you saved me